# Why is cpanminus installed using a single dash argument to the Perl interpreter?

Tags: perl, cpanm

When looking at [Cpanminus](http://search.cpan.org/~miyagawa/App-cpanminus-1.7043/lib/App/cpanminus.pm), I saw that one way to install it is the following:

```
curl -L https://cpanmin.us | perl - App::cpanminus
```

The first part downloads a file from the URL which can be interpreted by the Perl interpreter, and then pipes it to Perl. I can't figure out what the single dash argument is doing, though.

For that matter I'm not totally sure what the second argument is doing (why would Cpanminus need to know its own name?), but at least it looks less mysterious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first non-option argument passed to `perl` is the name of the file to execute. `-` indicates STDIN. Therefore, the command has `perl` execute the output of `curl -L https://cpanmin.us`, passing `App::cpanminus` as an argument.

Since `curl -L https://cpanmin.us` returns a self-contained version of `cpanm`, the whole command effectively downloads `cpanm` and uses it to install `cpanm` (a part of App::cpanminus).

In other words,

```
curl -L https://cpanmin.us | perl - App::cpanminus
```

is roughly the same as

```
curl -L https://cpanmin.us >self_contained_cpanm
perl self_contained_cpanm App::cpanminus
```

Comment: ... which, in turn, runs the cpanminus with the argument App::cpanminus, so it installs the library App:cpanminus, which provides cpanminus.